# Querying a subset of an array in Snowflake, including some values but excluding other values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am attempting to subset on certain elements within an array in a Snowflake database, including some elements but excluding others.

Example:

```
SELECT column1
FROM table
WHERE array_contains('cats'::variant, column1)
LIMIT 6;
```

with output:

```
Row column1
1 ["cats","dogs"]
2 ["horses","cows","cats"]
3 ["cats"]
4 ["cats","fish",turtles"]
5 ["cats","turtles","dogs"]
6 ["fish","cats"]
```

**BUT** how would I write a query that selects rows with "cats" in the array, but also excludes rows that have "cows" and "fish" even if "cats" is in those arrays as well? The goal would only be to return rows 1, 3, and 5 out of the above output, and exclude the other rows/arrays that have "cows" and/or "fish" in them even if "cats" happens to be in the array as well.

The desired subsetted output from above should be:

```
Row column1
1 ["cats","dogs"]
2 ["cats"]
3 ["cats","turtles","dogs"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `NOT`, `ARRAY_CONTAINS` and `AND`:

```sql
with t as (
    select array_construct('dogs', 'cats') column1
    union all select array_construct('dogs', 'cats', 'fish')
)

SELECT column1
FROM t
WHERE array_contains('cats'::variant, column1)
AND NOT array_contains('cows'::variant, column1);
AND NOT array_contains('fish'::variant, column1);
```

Comment: . . Wouldn't `arrays_overlap()` be simpler?